# How to make a Palatino TITLE in small caps?

Tags: fonts, titles, small-caps

I want my Palatino article font to be written with small caps. How do? So far I have

```
\setlength{\droptitle}{-4\baselineskip} % Move the title up
\pretitle{\begin{center}\Large\scshape\bfseries} % Article title formatting
\posttitle{\end{center}} % Article title closing formatting
\title{Collision Theory and Rutherford Scattering}
```

But the `\scshape` in the `\pretitle` is doing nothing, I just end up with regular lower case characters. However, for my `section` titles, I have nearly the same thing:

```
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\large\scshape\centering}{\thesection.}{1em}{}
```

(note the `\scshape`) and this works fine.

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 5):

`Palatino` is obsolete (no smallcaps, doesn't manage maths fonts). You should use `mathpazo` instead, which uses a Palatino-clone, `URW Palladio` (has smallcaps and (faked?) bold smallcaps, but no slanted small caps). Even better, load `newpxtext`  and `newpxmath`, based on `TeXGyrePagellaX` which has all 4 smallcaps and exist in OpenType format.

With `newpx`:

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[largesc]{newpxtext}
\usepackage{newpxmath}
% \usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{titling, titlesec}
\usepackage{slantsc} 

\setlength{\droptitle}{-4\baselineskip} % Move the title up
\pretitle{\begin{center}\Large\scshape\bfseries} % Article title formatting
\posttitle{\end{center}} % Article title closing formatting
\title{Collision Theory and Rutherford Scattering}

\titleformat{\section}[block]{\large\scshape\centering}{\thesection.}{0.5em}{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{A test section}

Normal font.

 \textbf{\textsc{Bold Small Caps}}

\textit{\scshape Italic Small Caps}

\end{document}
```

[image]
With `mathpazo`:

[image]

Comment: I am indeed using `mathpazo`, I just meant it is a Palatino font. Sorry about that. And I can indeed do everything that you've done here. But I can't make the title in small caps. Section titles and normal text is fine, it's just the article title that won't work. So, in the code you posted, if you add `\maketitle` somewhere after `\begin{document}`, you will see that the title will not be in small caps, even though I have `\scshape` in the `\pretitle`

Comment: Palatino has small caps but  only in the commercial version.  TeXGyrePagellaX is just another clone (some say close to Linotype Palatino) with all smallcaps and old-style numbers.

Comment: Ok. My question still stands

Comment: I do have bold smallcaps in title, both with `mathpazo` and `newpx`, and slanted smallcaps only with `newpx`.

Comment: Strange, I have exactly as you do and my title will not render with small caps, it just keeps coming out lower case. I am using `mathpazo`...

Edit: I just realized that I can get small caps titles if I change `\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}` to `\usepackage{mathpazo}`. Why is this? I can't find any documentation on `mathpazo`'s parameters.